# Is EF Core shared transaction a good solution here, or it is a bad design?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**Design**: I have a few entities and every entity has its own repository, they are  EntityRepositories. There is another repository representing a higher abstraction - I call them BusinessRepositories, and its methods use the EntityRepositories. My justification behind this is the following, entity repositories represent atomic, re-usable entity level operations, and they are easy to test. Business repository represent the business value and it is built on re-usable, well tested atomic operations, so testing can be cut back, or can just focus on business value, rather than atomic entity level operations implemented, unnecessarily, multiple times. I might over-engineered it a bit, it is a pet-project.

I got the point when I need transactions at business level. I'm reading the [shared transaction part of the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#cross-context-transaction-relational-databases-only) and I cannot figure out whether shared context is for me, or my described above design is wrong.

The doc suggest that I can pass through the transaction to EntityRepository, so I can do something like below. Part of the code is copy-pasted, another part is typed, so might have syntax error.

```
public class AEntityRepository : IAEntityRepository
    {
        private DbContextOptions _dbContextOptions;

        public AEntityRepository(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions)
        {
            _dbContextOptions = dbContextOptions;
        }

        public async Task<Dimension> ModifyAsync(
            Dimension entity,
            DbTransaction dbTransaction = null)
        {
            // stuff here
            using ( MasterDataContext ctx = new MasterDataContext(_dbContextOptions) )
            {
                ctx.Database.UseTransaction(dbTransaction.GetDbTransaction());
                // stuff here
            }
        }
}

public class BusinessRepository : IBusinessRepository
    {
        public async Task<BusinessObject> ModifyAsync(
            BusinessObject businessObject)
        {
            // stuff here
            using ( MasterDataContext ctx = new MasterDataContext(_dbContextOptions) )
            {
                using( var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                     try {
                         await _aEntityRepository.ModifyAsync(someObject, transaction.GetDbTransaction());
                         await _bEntityRepository.ModifyAsync(someObject, transaction.GetDbTransaction());
                         transaction.Commit();
                     } catch {
                         transaction.Rollback();
                     }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The expected behaviour in this case would be that, if something goes wrong in **_bEntityRepository.ModifyAsync()** then operations done by **_aEntityRepository.ModifyAsync()** rollbacked too.

**Question**: Am I on the right path, or my design is wrong?

Comment: I think you should share the context, not the transaction, and conclude each business method by one `SaveChanges` call. But this quesition is primarily opinion based.

Comment: One issue I see may cause problem is you are opening multiple instances of `new MasterDataContext()`. Your transaction context is different context on what's in your `ModifyAsync` context.

Comment: @penleychan In the example code they do the same. There are two instance from 'BloggingContext' (see the linked doc).

Comment: Sharing the context and having your top level business layer method call  `context.SaveChanges()`  will simplify things for you.

Comment: @shbht_twr You are right. Then the questions is that, what problem is solved by having shareable transaction?